# Vertically center CSS rule works for row but not for column in bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I am trying to use the following CSS rules to vertically center aligned content in bootstrap 3 -

```
.center {
   display:flex;
   align-items:center !important;
   background-color:red;
   text-align:center;     
}

@media ( min-width:768px ) {
  .center {
     display:flex;
     align-items:center !important;
     background-color:red;
     text-align:center;     
   }
}

@media ( min-width: 992px ) {
  .center {
   display:flex;
   align-items:center !important;
   background-color:red;
   text-align:center;     
  }
}
@media ( min-width: 1200px ) {
.center {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center !important;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;     
  }
}
```

And, here is my html

```
<div class="row center"> <!--if .center is here valign works-->
  <div class="col-sm-4"> <!--if .center is here valign doesn't work-->
     test
  </div>    
<div class="col-sm-8 ">
  test </br>
  test </br>
  test </br>
</div>
```

You can find it in [codepen.io.](http://codepen.io/skpaul/pen/ogdZjq)

Any help?

Comment: try this, remove `  display:flex;` attribute

Comment: @AkhilNamboothiri - removing display:flex is not working.

Comment: is this you expecting? check the [fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/Lkoc5gg1/)

Comment: @AkhilNamboothiri - perhaps you did not got my problem. Please read the problem again carefully.

Comment: I think so, can you provide an image for what you are trying?

Comment: @AkhilNamboothiri - The problem has been explained in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in two ways.

1. Using **Absolute position**
2. Using **display:table**

**USING ABSOLUTE POSITION**

DESC: Give parent element {{position:relative}} and child(element to be centered) as

```
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**USING  TABLE BLOCK**

DESC: Give parent element as `display:table;width:100%` and second parent as `display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;`

**Note***: {table-row} should have some height greater than its content.