# Fixed height + vertically aligned

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-frameworks, grid-system

I am having trouble getting a fixed height sections plus vertically aligned elements to follow grid responsive behavior. Only constraint is that sections should have a fixed size.

I have seen examples on SO but it breaks columns stacking behavior.

See attached jpeg on what I am trying to accomplish.

[image: grid layout]

Comment: for vertical alignment this might help you out..    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675080/vertically-center-css-rule-works-for-row-but-not-for-column-in-bootstrap3/28804239#28804239                  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use position [relative](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

```css
section {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
  </div>
</section>
```