# vertically center bootstrap accordion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion, vertical-alignment, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to center the accordion content vertically when it is opened, so whatever is in there is displayed in the center of the screen; the code can be seen via dev tools at [www.webwoods.co.uk/lsss/installation.html](http://www.webwoods.co.uk/lsss/installation.html)

would prefer a CSS solution, JS if no choice

Comment: [LINK][1]

This link might help you out.
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28804239/3017788

Comment: Linked page is blocked for me...a fiddle would be helpful

Comment: thanks guys, I will try to do a fiddle tomorrow morning

Comment: fiddle for this is too fiddly (excuse the pun), thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this (it works for me):

To .panel-body, .col-md-8 and .col-md-4 add "display: table-cell;" and to .col-md-8 and .col-md-4 - "float: none; vertical-align: middle;"

note: .panel-default > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse .panel-body -- will overwritte simple .panel-body

Comment: didn't work, completely messes up alignment for other elements.

Comment: maybe a js/jquery solution that just scrolls the screen to display the accordion content in the middle?

Comment: I can not format this comment well and sorry about that. Just aded at the end of style.css (via chrome developer tool):

.panel-default > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse .panel-body, .col-md-8, .col-md-4 {display: table-cell;}
.col-md-8, .col-md-4  {float: none; vertical-align: middle;}

Text end images is vericaly aligned.

Comment: tried that, it messes up the alignment for the elements, plus, doesn't bring the content to the middle of the screen; I tried it in Firefox though, maybe a browser-specific bug; will try in Chrome and post the results here